# Zipping a folder and sub-directories not working without sudo?

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, sudo

I wrote a python script using Amazon's AWS Boto3 SDK to download files from an S3 bucket and puts them in a folder (in a directory within my home dir). For reference, the function I used was [the s3 client's download_file()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/download_file.html)

When I ran the python script, I got a `Permission Denied` error so I ran the script with `sudo` and it worked, creating the folder with the files in it.

I'm using the zip tool to simply zip up the folder via `zip -r output.zip folder_path/`
but for some reason, this command creates an empty zip file unless I run the command above with `sudo`.

Why is that?

Given that this is in a folder within my `home/user/` directory, why do the files need sudo to be accessed? Is it possible that the files being downloaded are being created without normal permissions?

The permissions I see are as follows for the files: `-rw------- 1 root root`

For the folder it's the same plus execute permissions (i.e. `chmod 700`)